# Spring Security in OSGi

Tags: spring-security, osgi

We have one security bundle and several application bundles, say X, Y and Z. We use Spring Security to secure all the URLs exposed by X, Y and Z. When a new bundle is added, say Q, we need to modify the security bundle and redeploy to secure the URLs of he Q bundle.

Is there a better way to implement Spring Security for multiple bundles?

Is Spring Security not the right choice?

Ideally, I would like the security bundle to expose an auth service and the bundles X, Y, Z, Q use that auth service to register the URL security configs when the respective bundles becomes active. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not let every application manage its own secured URLs? Have a security bundle which exposes the common services (authentication-manager, authentication-provider etc) but let everything else be handled by the application itself.

Comment: When the individual bundles would register with common services (auth manager) the Spring security filter chain proxy needs to be recreated. Is that the model you are suggesting?